# Append before parent after getSelection()

Tags: javascript

I have one question. I try to develop a little WYSIWYG editor.

I would like create a `<h1>` button which allows me to generate a `<h1>` title (by clicking on button after text selection in `<p>` element).

I obtain the selection with `window.getSelection()...`. But now, I would like to put my `append("<h1>my text selected</h1>")` just before the `<p>`. It’s my problem, because my `<p>` elements don’t have `id` or `class`. So do you know a means to put my append just before the `<p>` where my text has been selected?

I don’t know if with my bad English you’ll understand me!

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com)?

```
$("#yourButton").click(
    function(){
      $('<h1>'+window.getSelection()+'</h1>').insertBefore("???");
    }
);
```

Just replace `"???"` with the location of your `<p>` element. How you would find that location depends how you wrote your HTML. Feel free to post your HTML for more assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Please find my HTML :

<div id="my_editeur" contenteditable="true">
<p>Voici mon premier paragraphe.</p>
<p>Voici mon second paragraphe.</p>
<p>Voici mon troisième paragraphe.</p>
<p>Voici mon quatrième paragraphe.</p>
</div>

In this case for example I would like to transform "Voici mon troisième" in h1 title, and to insert it before the third <p>

Comment: You're missing a step. So far I have:

1. Select text from `p`
2. ?
3. Place text in new `h1` above `p`

Comment: 1. I select my text from '<p>'
2. I click on button $('#btn_h1'). I use getSelected() function to obtain my selection ('var selection = getSelected();')
3. I would like to place my selection in new '<h1>' above the '<p>' where I have select the text?